# Comet server on a web-garden

Tags: c#, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, comet, web-garden

I am using an `IHttpAsyncHandler` to serve a comet / long-polling request. The handler holds the connection open and saves the `MyAsyncResult` object in a static `ConcurrentSet<MyAsyncResult>`.

When a separate request is made (the request that causes the comet to response), the program finds the `MyAsyncResult` object in the list and completes the request.

My problem is, when I change my application to run in a Webgarden, this static variable isn't going to be shared across all the worker processes, so this implementation isn't going to work..

Now, I have no way of storing the `MyAsyncResult` object in an SQL database, or any kind of object that could be useful (like the `IHttpHandler` itself, or a delegate pointing to the EndProcessRequest method, etc). I could store certain IDs and strings in an SQL database and continuously check for new values, but this seems expensive and kind of defeats the object of using long-polling in the first place.

Is there any way I can share my static `ConcurrentSet` across a webgarden? Or any other way I can get the `IHttpAsyncHandler` that is sat there waiting for the signal to send it's response?

**Edit:**

If there is no way I can share variables across processes, is there a way I can broadcast to all other worker processes? All I'd need here is a single signal with two integer parameters.